# Rotar una imagen bmp en java

Tags: java, imagen

Este código funciona,  lee un archivo en tipo byte y  después de asignarle la imagen crea una copia en el directorio donde se encuentra la otra parte con un nombre diferente, debo de hacer lo mismo, crear un nuevo archivo, solo debo de lograr que gire en los ejes X y Y como la imagen final de 180 grados sin crear alguna librería que haga el trabajo.

```
public class BMPRotations {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int contador=0;
        
        int datos_entrada[] = new int[921655];
        
        
        try {
            FileInputStream archivo_lectura = new FileInputStream("Ruta_Donde_Esta_la_Imagen_picture.bmp");
            boolean final_ar = false;
            
            while(!final_ar) {
                int byte_entrada = archivo_lectura.read();
                
                if(byte_entrada!=-1)
                    
                    datos_entrada[contador]=byte_entrada;
                else
                    final_ar=true;
                
                //Muestra todos los bytes 
                //System.out.println(datos_entrada[contador]);
                
                contador++;
                
            }
            archivo_lectura.close();
            
        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Error al acceder a la imagen");
            
            
        }
        System.out.print("Bystes de la imagen: " + contador);
        
        crea_fichero(datos_entrada);
    }
    static void crea_fichero(int datos_nuevo_fichero[]) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fichero_nuevo = new FileOutputStream("Ruta_Donde_Esta_la_Imagen_picture.bmp");
            
            for(int i=0; i<datos_nuevo_fichero.length;i++) {
                fichero_nuevo.write(datos_nuevo_fichero[i]);
                
            }
            
            fichero_nuevo.close();
            
            
            
        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al crear el archivo");
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano,

la imagen se debe de ver así

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz4A4.png

Comment: Y dónde está el error? Cómo has intentado girarlo?

Comment: @Benito-B eso he intendado pero no me sale nada, ese programa corre pero busco alguien que me ayude o informacion que me ayude si fueras tan amable

Answer (score 1):

Puedes rotar una imagen muy fácilmente y con buscar un poco se puede encontrar muchas respuestas, quizás no específicamente de un archivo BMP y guardarlo, pero se puede encontrar todo lo necesario como para armar lo que necesites, incluso algunos problemas que tiene ImageIO y BufferedImage al escribir un archivo con extensión BMP.

En la mayoría paginas tienen este código https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-to-rotate-an-image/ el cual modifique para adaptarlo a archivos BMP, ademas tienes que usar `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` para evitar errores ya que ImageIO no puede escribir una imagen BMP con transparencia (se entiende que antes era ARGB con getType)

Para esto tenes que crear un BufferedImage con la imagen original, luego crear otro BufferedImage donde se pintara los gráficos del primer BufferedImage rotados.

Se usa `rotate(double theta, double x, double y)` para especificar una rotación y luego se dibujan los gráficos del primer BufferedImage `drawImage(image, null, 0, 0)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate(double,%20double,%20double)

Y para gurdarlo lo de siempre `ImageIO.write(image, format, target);`

```
private void save(File source, File target, String format, int degrees) {
    try {
        
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(source);
        
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        
        BufferedImage newBuffered = new BufferedImage(
                width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        
        Graphics2D g2 = newBuffered.createGraphics();           
        
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), width / 2, height / 2);
        g2.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);
        
        g2.dispose();
        
        ImageIO.write(newBuffered, format, target);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Para guardar la imagen

```
File origen = new File("/home/abcde/Desktop/image.bmp");
File destino = new File("/home/abcde/Desktop/image2.bmp");
    
save(origen, destino, "BMP", 180);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, si es que me toca hacerlo sin ninguna librería que haga el trabajo y eso es lo que no logro, pero me ayudaste mucho, gracias!